# U-boot Splashscreen through SPI

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, u-boot

I am trying to configure a splashscreen in u-boot on an orange pi zero plus using Armbian.

The screen is connected through spi1 using the ST7789v chip of the LCD.

I already have used systemd to display a splashscreen however I find it slow to display something. It display something only after ~12 sec. I could probably reduce that time a bit by loading the service earlier but it would never start in 5 sec.

It seems that u-boot [doesn't take in charge spi as a video output](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/53240275666acf32cb9811e44eaf2fd571a6cb75/doc/README.video). I can see LCD, HDMI, DVI, VGA,... but no SPI. Is it possible to configure the SPI as LCD? Or to send framebuffer to the SPI to display the splashscreen?

Comment: So, a driver for a device that you have is missing from upstream. So [write your own video driver for u-boot](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/tree/53240275666acf32cb9811e44eaf2fd571a6cb75/drivers/video).

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I wanted to avoid this step. I was hoping that there were another way. I have never developed a driver for u-boot before.

Answer (score 2):

As @KamilCuk mentioned there is no ST7789V driver in U-Boot yet. But you could write your own.

In Linux there is a frame buffer driver drivers/staging/fbtft/fb_st7789v.c which could serve as a template.

On the U-Boot side you can use drivers/video/lg4573.c as a template for a SPI  framebuffer driver.

Additionally to the driver you will a device tree overlay describing the SPI device. See Documentation/devicetree/bindings/display/panel/sitronix,st7789v.yaml of the Linux kernel.

Please, send your patches upstream.

Comment: Thank you @Xypron, and what do you think of this linux driver instead ? https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-sitronix-st7789v.c, is there a difference?

Comment: According to patch 7142afb3a186 ("drm/panel: Add driver for sitronix ST7789V LCD controller") the drm driver is not for SPI but for RGB/Parallel. I have not used either of both drivers personally.

Comment: Which of the drivers did you use for the output in systemd? lsmod should show which one is loaded.

Comment: From lsmod, the driver used is fb_st7789v indeed. But I am trying to use the drm driver instead without success now. In the commit message I see _The Sitronix ST7789v controller is used to drive 240x320 LCD panels through various interfaces, including **SPI** and RGB/Parallel._

Comment: Did you manage to get the splash screen running with this fb_st7789v driver and kernel? @waelabd